# How do I write postgres conditional SELECT query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has 3 columns.

```
id | name | score | approve
--------------------
1  | foo  |  90   |   f
2  | foo  |  80   |   t
```

I want to

```
SELECT id WHERE name='foo'
```

with these conditions:

1. if `approve` is True, then return that one (only one will be true for the same name)
2. otherwise select the one that has highest score

I was looking into `IF`...`ELSE` but cannot even come up with a query that executes (despite a working one...)

How to set up the query command for this type of queries?

Comment: what if there are more users with the same highest score?

Comment: @RadimBača good question. In this case we can choose just one of them. Doesn't have to be random so it can always return the same person. We don't expect this to happen though as the score is actually going to 8 digits after decimal instead of an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can often use some logic by defining the right order and limit:

```
select id
from my_table
where name = 'foo'
order by approve desc, score desc
limit 1
```